# Cannot Call Value of Non Function Type Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, swift3

I am trying to convert my project to swift 3 but get the following error on my code:

Code:

```
super.collectionView(collectionView, willDisplayCell: cell, forItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Error:

Cannot Call Value of Non-function type 'uicollectionview'

Does anyone know the swift 3 edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing a UICollectionViewController you should be able to use this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    super.collectionView(collectionView, willDisplay: cell, forItemAt: indexPath)
}
```

If you are not subclassing a UICollectionViewController you will likely have to use this:

```
@objc(collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:) func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

I have both types of collection views in my apps that I've been updating, and that is what works for me.